# Countdown hook loses 1 second every minute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm implementing a countdown in my react-native app, but something is not working properly.

It seems that the countdown loses 1 seconds every minute (as you can see in the gif, it jumps between 33 and 31)

[image: bug example]

this is the code:

```
import {
  differenceInDays,
  differenceInHours,
  differenceInMinutes,
  differenceInSeconds,
  isBefore,
  parseISO,
} from 'date-fns'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

type CountdownResult = {
  days: number
  hours: number
  minutes: number
  seconds: number
}

const calculateInitialDuration = (endDate: string, today: Date): CountdownResult => {
  const futureDate = new Date(endDate)
  const days = differenceInDays(futureDate, today)
  const hours = differenceInHours(futureDate, today) % 24
  const minutes = differenceInMinutes(futureDate, today) % 60
  const seconds = differenceInSeconds(futureDate, today) % 60
  return { days, hours, minutes, seconds }
}

const EXPIREDRESULT: CountdownResult = { days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0 }

// TODO: FIXME: sometimes the countdown jumps directly between 2 seconds
// even if the real time passed is 1 second
// this was happening before the refactor too
const useCountdown = (endDate: string): CountdownResult => {
  const today = new Date()
  const formattedEndDate = parseISO(endDate)
  // doing this because at the beginning countdown seems stuck on the first second
  // maybe there is a better solution for this problem
  const initialCountdown = calculateInitialDuration(endDate, today)
  initialCountdown.seconds++

  const [time, setTime] = useState(isBefore(formattedEndDate, today) ? EXPIREDRESULT : initialCountdown)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isBefore(formattedEndDate, today)) return
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(calculateInitialDuration(endDate, today))
    }, 1000)
    return (): void => clearInterval(intervalId)
  }, [time])
  return time
}

export default useCountdown
```

`endDate` is a string following the **ISO 8601** format.
I'm using **date-fns** but I also tried the basic javascript implementation, bug is still the same.

Another strange thing is that the countdown, at the beginning, is stuck for one second on the first second (that's the reason why I created the `initialCountdown` variable), but actually I don't like the solution.

Any tips? Where are the mistakes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SetInterval()` is not guaranteed to be executed exactly every 1000 milliseconds!

Comment: thanks for you comment @phuzi , do you have some suggestion? a different implementation?

Comment: See my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are assuming that `setInterval()` triggers the callback every 1,000 milliseconds.

```js
    setInterval(() => {
      setTime(calculateInitialDuration(endDate, today))
    }, 1000)
```

Unfortunately, with everything else that browser has to do, there's no guarantee that it will.

What you will need to do to gain more accuracy is repeatedly use `setTimeout()` calculating how long to set the timeout for.

```js
let timeout;

const start = (() => {
  // IIFE because func needs to be able to reference itself!
  let func = () => {
    // Do whatever you need to do here
    let now = new Date();
    
    let timeToNextSecond = 1000 - (now.getTime() % 1000);
    console.log('Now: ', now, 'TimeToNext: ', timeToNextSecond);
    timeout = setTimeout(func, timeToNextSecond);
  };
  return func;
})();

const stop = () => clearTimeout(timeout);

start();
// wait 10 seconds(ish)
setTimeout(stop, 10000);
```

If you run this, you will see that subsequent timeouts run shortly after the start of the next second. Assuming that the browser isn't bogged down doing other stuff, it will run every second.

**Thoughts:** I imagine that `setInterval` does something like this behind the scenes, just with a fixed timeout causing the drift.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, also just adding the `timeToNextSecond` mechanism on my `setInterval` also does the trick (and makes me remove the `initialCountdown` variable!